# Core Data: How to fault freshly created managed objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am creating new managed objects in a loop, save them and would like to fault them right after saving them to reduce the RAM footprint.

This is how I create the managed objects:

```
[objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PFObject *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   @autoreleasepool {
   ForexHistory *forexHistory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:localEntityName 
   inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
   forexHistory.date = obj[@"date"];
   }
}];
NSError *saveError = nil;
[backgroundContext save:&saveError];
```

In order to fault the objects, I understand that I need to use `refreshObjects:mergeChanges`.

Do I need to refetch all inserted objects in order to iterate over them and send `refreshObjects:mergeChanges:NO` to each of them or is there a better way?

Comment: How many objects are there? Did you profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know, whether I understood your question correct.

You can wipe-out a moc with [`-reset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/reset). All references to objects become invalid. You have to refetch them.

Comment: Wouldn't resetting the moc flush all its objects? I just want to specific entities (like `forexhistory`in my code sample).

Comment: It flushes all objects.

Comment: That`s why I would prefer refreshing only specific managed objects instead of the full moc. The way I am currently doing this is storing references to the newly created managed objects in a set, saving the moc and then iterating over the set to fault its objects (`refresh:mergeChanges:NO`). What is your view on this?

Comment: If you want to handle specific objects you should need a collection with specific objects, don't you?